# Python image recognition - accessing the dataset

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python program to recognize characters on images. I've already chosen a method of recognition and it's not what I'm having the problem with. It's the dataset access that bothers me. We are given a training dataset (pickle file), which contains images stored in a form of a single matrix `(NxD)`. Each row is one, 60x60 image. We are supposed to implement a function that for matrix `X` will give us a vector `y` of predicted class of labels (label being {0...35} - a character/digit that's recognized on the image).

Now, I've read on the topic and all, I'm using HOG for feature extraction, along with a `get_features` function. I can't understand though how am I supposed to assign `x_train` and `x_val`, as well as `y_train` and `y_val`, having only what I have in my .pkl file. I decided to try and split the dataset into `x_train` and `x_val` randomly, 50-50. I'm getting `y` vector filled along the way, so should I split it up to get `y_val` as well? So far, I have this code for my final function (+ first I load the data):

```
def load_data():
    PICKLE_FILE_PATH = 'train.pkl'
    with open(PICKLE_FILE_PATH, 'rb') as f:
        return pkl.load(f)

def final():
    """ 
    :param x: matrix NxD
    :return: vector Nx1
    """
    train = load_data()
    x = get_features(train['x'])
    N, D = x.shape
    y = np.zeros((N, 1))
    np.random.shuffle(x)
    x_train = x[:50]
    x_val = x[50:]
    # calling functions i'm using for recognition....
    return y
```

Now, I'm getting an error that says:

```
    x = get_features(train['x'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

After analyzing it for forever, I assume that in .pkl, the `(NxD)` matrix has one element per row, since it's supposed to contain one image per row. Maybe I'm seeing it wrong? Maybe there is no `'x'` in .pkl yet, just a nameless matrix? I got lost and I just want to understand how to transform that bit of data I'm given in the .pkl file to my familiar variables, `x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val` which I all need for recognition. Any tips would be great!

Answer (score 0):

if you want the first elemnt of a tuple you must do:

```
x = get_features(train[0])
```

Comment: so this would be for the first image, right? if i want to do this for all of them, i guess id need a loop... but is it necessary, isn't there another way to do it? i tried [:] but i think i should mention that one(?) column too...